# update and delete query based on select query mysql

Tags: mysql

how to solve this at single query in mysql

first select status and instituteId from table:

```
select instituteId, status from reviews where reviewId='10'.
```

if status is 1 then want to update and delete from tables like,

```
   update institutions SET institutions.overallRatings=(SELECT 
   avg(b.averageRating) FROM reviews a INNER JOIN reviews b ON 
   b.instituteId=a.instituteId WHERE a.reviewId='10' AND b.status='1') WHERE 
   institutions.instituteId=(SELECT instituteId FROM reviews WHERE 
   reviewId='10')
```

suppose if status is 0 then only delete,

```
DELETE FROM reviews WHERE reviewId='10'
```

Comment: You cannot update and delete in a single statement. You might consider a procedure.

Comment: or can use mysql function / procedure for this queries?

Comment: then how to create a procedure for this query?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html

Answer (score 0):

This procedure should do what you have asked for. It takes the desired `reviewId` as a parameter (`rid`). First it selects `instituteId` and `status` into 2 variables `iid` and `sts`. Then if `sts=1` it performs the update. Finally it deletes the appropriate review. Note that it uses the variable `iid` to avoid a second subquery in the `UPDATE`.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE update_institution(IN rid VARCHAR(10))
BEGIN
  DECLARE iid, sts INT;
  SELECT instituteId, status INTO iid, sts FROM reviews WHERE reviewId=rid;
  IF sts = 1 THEN
     UPDATE institutions 
     SET institutions.overallRatings=(SELECT AVG(b.averageRating) 
                                      FROM reviews a 
                                      INNER JOIN reviews b 
                                      ON b.instituteId=a.instituteId 
                                      WHERE a.reviewId=rid AND b.status=1)
     WHERE institutions.instituteId=iid;
   END IF;
   DELETE FROM reviews WHERE reviewId=rid;
END //
DELIMITER ;
CALL update_institution('10');
```

Note that this procedure assumes that the only valid values of `reviews.status` are 0 and 1. If not, you would need to put an `IF` around the `DELETE`:

```
IF sts = 0 OR sts = 1 THEN
  DELETE FROM reviews WHERE reviewId=rid;
END IF;
```

Also it assumes based on your question that `reviewId` is a `VARCHAR`. If this is not the case you would need to adjust the parameter type appropriately (probably to `INT`).

Finally I don't really understand why you have a `JOIN` in your subquery in the `UPDATE`, it is completely unnecessary for what it is doing. You could rewrite it as:

```
SELECT AVG(averageRating) 
FROM reviews
WHERE reviewId=rid AND b.status=1
```

Ok, that wasn't quite finally. For this to work there must only be one review with a given `reviewId`. So taking the average (using `AVG`) is pointless and the `UPDATE` subquery could be simplified further to:

```
SELECT averageRating
FROM reviews
WHERE reviewId=rid AND b.status=1
```

Comment: Did this not solve your problem? If not, can you provide more information to help solve it?